# Best practices for rebase, squashing and incorporating only my changes?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to rebasing.  I've already pushed some changes to my fork, to a branch used only by me.  The goal is to eventually open a pull request on github to incorporate this branch's changes into our master branch.

Here's what I did:  With my own branch checked out I ran `git pull --rebase` to get the latest version of our origin's master branch and rebase my changes on top of it.

I next ran `git rebase -i HEAD~8`, where `8` was a number I chose that I knew would encompass all of my branch commits.  From the resulting list of commits I didn't touch any that had nothing to do with my branch, and squashed those pertaining to my branch.

I then did a force push to my branch, and went to open a pull request.  To my surprise, all 8 of the commits I chose were included in the pull request.

Obviously I have a bit to learn about this.  Why did all 8 commits wind up in the pull reqeust, and how can I improve in the future so that only my branch commits wind up in there?  (And if my commits are woven in with other commits on master, how can I avoid including others in the list when I call `rebase -i` or at least keep them from going up with the PR?)

Did I make a mistake in rebasing against the origin's master branch, and not my fork's master?  Should I have pulled and merged origin/master into myfork/master, then rebased against myfork/master?

Comment: I'm confused why your branches changes are interspersed with changes that are not yours...or are they yours but not relevant to your branch? Anyway, during rebase -i summary view, if you remove the lines with the commits you don't want to appear in the rebased tree, those won't appear in your new branch. If you diff against master, though, you'll get the inverse of those changes if they were indeed in master. I think it sounds like you're rebasing wrong, although I'm not sure why. I would do `git fetch` followed by `git rebase origin/master` and then squash your changes myself.

Comment: Thanks.  The steps described above are what I 'think' I should be doing during a rebase, but as you noted (and I mentioned in my caveat at the top) that doesn't mean it's what I should be doing.
The 'interspersed' changes I saw in my pull request were from the master branch.

Comment: Ok, so trying to get this straight: at the point you ran `git pull --rebase`, are you pulling from your fork's master or the upstream master? Immediately thereafter, if you ran `git log` the changes from your local branch are interspersed with changes you just pulled?

Comment: Also, has your fork's master diverged from upstream master? And do all of the changes you wish to submit live on the branch in your fork you mention?

Comment: I ran `git pull --rebase` against the upstream master.  And if I'd run `git log` in this particular instance, the changes would not have been interspersed (I was speaking hypothetically on that.)
As for my fork diverging from upstream master, I update it daily but it's possible at the time I did this they were slightly out of sync.  As to your last question, all of my changes I wanted to push lived on my branch, in my fork.

Answer (score 2):

> I next ran git rebase -i HEAD~8, where 8 was a number I chose

You should not need to do that. Just `git rebase -i` without extra argument would do the right thing with recent enough versions of git if you have configured your upstream branch properly. At worse, `git rebase origin/master` will do the right thing.

> I then did a force push

Not needed either in this use-case. You're supposed to rewrite only local commits using `git rebase`, hence you need a normal push, and `--force` is shooting yourself in the foot.

*If* your first pull-request is not good enough, and you need to rework it by rewriting some commits, *then* you may want to update your PR with a force push.

> I didn't touch any that had nothing to do with my branch

If the remote history is linear (no merge) and you really did not touch (i.e. no line removal, no line reordering, really no change) the beginning, then `git` will not rewrite these commits. But if there's a merge between `HEAD` and `HEAD~8`, then `git rebase` will flatten it by default, and if you modified something before a `pick` command, then the `pick` command will replay the changes introduced by the commit on top of the new history. This will result in a *new* commit that is identical to the old one to your eyes, but with a new identifier (sha1), hence it is seen as different by git and github, and appears in the pull-request.